# User Control Button Click Event Not Raised

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I  have a User Control that has been added to the page dynamically.  When I click a button on that user control:

1. The button_click event is NOT being raised
2. The page posts back
3. The user control is removed from the page

Here's the button-click event on my User Control:

```
 Protected Sub btnAddAttribute_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddAttribute.Click
      Try
           Dim attrName As String = txtAddAttributeName.Text
           Dim attrValue As String = txtAddAttributeValue.Text

           'ADD ATTRIBUTE TO ATTRIBUTE TABLE
           putSQLData("INSERT INTO OD_Attribute_Values (AttributeName, AttributeValue) VALUES('" & attrValue & "', '" & attrName & "'")

           'ADD ATTRIBUTE TO PRODUCT DATA FOR THIS PRODUCT
           putSQLData("UPDATE OD_Product_Data SET VariantMapping = VariantMapping + ' | " & attrName & ":" & attrValue & "' WHERE SKU = '" & SelectedSKU & "'")

           'ADD NEW ctrlAttribute TO PARENT PLACEHOLDER AND SET VALUES
           Dim newAttr As New AttributeControl
           newAttr.AttributeName = attrName
           newAttr.AttributeValue = attrValue
           Page.Controls.AddAt(Page.FindControl("phAttributes").ClientID, newAttr)

           'REMOVE THIS CONTROL FROM PARENT PLACEHOLDER
           Me.Dispose()

      Catch ex As Exception
           Common.SendError(ex.Message, "AttributeControl.btnAddAttribute_Click")
      End Try
 End Sub
```

Here is the dynamic adding of controls:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
      'WEB TAB
      getAttributes()
 End Sub

     Protected Sub getAttributes()
      Try
           Dim attr As String = ""
           Dim attrName As String = ""
           Dim attrValue As String = ""

           Dim ds As DataSet = getSQLData("SELECT VariantMapping FROM OD_Product_Data WHERE SKU='" & selectedSKU & "'")
           For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows()
                attr = dr(0).ToString
           Next
           ds = Nothing
           Dim attrArr As Array = attr.Split("|")
           For Each item As String In attrArr
                Dim attrDetail As Array = item.Split(":")
                attrName = attrDetail(0)
                attrValue = attrDetail(1)
                Dim ctrlAttributes As AttributeControl = LoadControl("ctrlAttribute.ascx")
                ctrlAttributes.AttributeName = attrName
                ctrlAttributes.AttributeValue = attrValue
                ctrlAttributes.ID = "ctrlAttribute-" & attrName
                phAttributes.Controls.Add(ctrlAttributes)
           Next
      Catch ex As Exception
           SendError(ex.Message, "Default.getAttributes")
      End Try
 End Sub

 Protected Sub btnAddAttribute_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddAttribute.Click
      Dim ctrlAttributes As AttributeControl = LoadControl("ctrlAttribute.ascx")
      ctrlAttributes.ID = "ctrlAttribute" & phAttributes.Controls.Count + 1
      phAttributes.Controls.Add(ctrlAttributes)
 End Sub

 Protected Sub btnCreateAttribute_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateAttribute.Click
      Dim ctrlAddAttribute As AddAttributeControl = LoadControl("ctrlAddAttribute.ascx")
      ctrlAddAttribute.SelectedSKU = selectedSKU
      ctrlAddAttribute.ID = "ctrlAddAttribute" & phAttributes.Controls.Count + 1
      phAttributes.Controls.Add(ctrlAddAttribute)
 End Sub
```

Comment: Posting your code would be helpful, this seems like either the event handler is not setup correctly or the PostBack is causing unexpected behavior

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you screaming in your code comments?

Comment: Are you making sure that your control is persisting after the page reloads. Like Random said, it would be a lot more helpful to see the code where the control is being called.

Comment: B/c I do 2 types of comments when I'm coding.  1 is lower case.  Those I get rid of before deployment.  The all-caps I keep in the code after deployment, for future reference.

Comment: You should post at least the code where you add the control dynamically to the page. Where do you remove the control from the page? Me.Dispose marks the object as disposable for the Garbage Collector but doesn:t remove it from the naming containr's control colleection.

Comment: Good point about the Me.Dispose.  I haven't gotten to the point of testing that out yet.  Makes sense...I'll figure new code to remove it from the placeholder...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When adding controls dynamically to a page you **must** be certain to add the control to the page **on each and every visit**. It's a common mistake to add the dynamic control on the first visit but *not* on postbacks - this won't work! You need to add the dynamic controls to the control hierarchy on every visit.

Here are a couple of resources I recommend reading before working with dynamically-created controls:

- [Dynamic Controls in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131055/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx)
- [Working with Dynamically Created Controls](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133936/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082102-1.aspx)
- [Truly Understanding Dynamic Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)
- [Creating Dynamic Data User Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479330.aspx)
- [Creating a Dynamic, Data-Driven User Interface](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113918/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082008-1.aspx)

Happy Programming!

Comment: Thanks!  I read the information you linked.

But, I didn't find the answer.

Here's what happens maybe you can point me in the right direction.

1. The page loads
2. The user clicks a button on the page that adds a User Control to a placeholder on the page
3. The user then clicks a button on that User Control

When the postback occurs the user control that triggered the postback is lost, and the event handler (on the user control) for that particular event is not triggered.

How do I tell the page to re-add the control that was born in #2 and raise the button click event on that control?

Comment: @s15199d: You're going to have to remember, somehow, what control(s) were added. You could store some flag in view state on the page, that would probably be best. I don't have a cut and dry answer for you because I've never worked with dynamic controls in this manner. All of my past experience in this area has been dynamically loading controls based on configuration in the database somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I follwed your advice and got it to mostly work for me.  Every time I add a control dynamically, I add it's control.ID to a ViewState variable, then on Page_Load I parse that viewstate variable and re-add my dynamically added controls.  Seems to be mostly working.  I have a few more elements of this to work through...

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not getting back to you earlier. I was going to say that you need to track the controls you add in some manner - view state (probably the best), session, database, form fields on the page... something. I've done a lot of work with dynamic controls in ASP.NET apps over the years but, to be honest, never in the way you described. Usually it's that I know what controls to load based on some already-set configuration (in a database, typically).

Answer (score 0):

Neat workaround found here: http://www.justskins.com/forums/placeholder-child-of-child-49926.html.

Comment: I'm not going this route personally, but it's an interesting tactic for anyone else looking to deal in this space.